# Objective c isKindOfClass missunderstanding?

Tags: objective-c, instanceof

I have following structure of objects:

Animal, Dog and Cat. As You expect Dog and Cat are inherited from Animal.

And I've a farm class:

```
 @implementation AnimalFarm

-(Animal*) createAnimal:(AnimalType)type{

  switch (type) {

    case CAT:
      return [Cat new];

    case DOG:
      return [Dog new];

    default:
      return [Animal new];
  }

}

@end
```

and I tried to unit test:

```
  AnimalFarm *farm = [AnimalFarm new];

  Animal *dog = [farm createAnimal:DOG];
  Animal *cat = [farm createAnimal:CAT];

  STAssertTrue([cat isMemberOfClass:[Cat class]],@"cat is not a cat!");
  STAssertTrue([dog isMemberOfClass:[Dog class]],@"Dog is not a dog!");

  STAssertTrue([cat isKindOfClass:[Animal class]],@"Cat is not an animal!");
  STAssertTrue([dog isKindOfClass:[Animal class]],@"Cat is not an animal!");
```

Implementation of classes:

```
@interface Cat : Animal {

}


@end

@implementation Cat

  -(NSString*) say{
    return @"miau";
}

@end
```

Implementation of dog is similar.

but neither isKindOfClass or isMemberOfClass worked as I expected....

Am I missing something?

---

When I use IFs instead of switch then everything goes well ... but what is the difference?

Implementation of createAnimal which works:

```
-(Animal *) createAnimal:(AnimalType)type {

  if (type == DOG) {
    return [Dog new]; 
  } else if (type == CAT) {
    return [Cat new]; 
  } else {
    return [Animal new];
  }
```

Comment: To clarify: Both `isMemberOfClass:` and `isKindOfClass:` are returning NO in those examples?

Comment: And are you getting any warnings during compilation?

Comment: Can we see the definition of `CAT` and `DOG`? Also, what do you mean "didn't work as I expected"? What are the results of the assertions?

Comment: What's not working?  Are the tests failing?  If so, which ones?

Comment: Your problem lies elsewhere.  Can you post the source somewhere?

Comment: Nowhere in the code you have posted are the `CAT` and `DOG` constants defined.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`isMemberOfClass:` will only return `YES` if the instance's class is exactly the same, however `isKindOfClass:` will return `YES` if the instance's class is the same, or a subclass of the given class.

For example this will output `No!`:

```
BOOL result = [[NSMutableArray array] isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]];
NSLog (@"%@", result? @"Yes!" : @"No!");
```

But this will output `Yes!`:

```
BOOL result = [[NSMutableArray array] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]];
NSLog (@"%@", result? @"Yes!" : @"No!");
```

This is because an NSMutableArray is a *kind* of NSArray, but it isn't a member of the NSArray class (otherwise it wouldn't be an NSMutableArray).

Throughout Foundation and Cocoa, there are a number of "class clusters". You can read more about this in the documentation on [Apple's developer web site](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW32). Due to the nature of class clusters, if you create perhaps an `NSString` object, it may fail the `isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]` test.

If neither `isKindOfClass:` or `isMemberOfClass:` is returning the correct value, see what class the actual object is with

```
NSLog(@"cat class = %@, dog class = %@", [cat className], [dog className]);
```

If these are returning anything other than what they are supposed to, then there is a problem with your farm class.

Comment: output of log is: cat class = Cat, dog class = Dog
I've tried to change new with alloc and init but the result is still the same. 

As you can see I compare correct classes using isMemberOfClass so It should return YES as well as isKindOfClass

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies elsewhere.

I created your `Animal`, `Dog`, and `Cat` classes, and the four cases you have above passed.  For reference, here is my code:  http://pastie.org/774468

It outputs:

```
2010-01-11 19:45:10.259 EmptyFoundation[83698:a0f] [cat isMemberOfClass:[Cat class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:45:10.265 EmptyFoundation[83698:a0f] [dog isMemberOfClass:[Dog class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:45:10.265 EmptyFoundation[83698:a0f] [cat isKindOfClass:[Animal class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:45:10.273 EmptyFoundation[83698:a0f] [dog isKindOfClass:[Animal class]] PASSED
```

EDIT:

I suppose there was a slight possibility that your `AnimalFarm` object was the source of the error, but I just tried creating the animal objects that way and got the same results (code: http://pastie.org/774480):

```
2010-01-11 19:51:35.144 EmptyFoundation[83741:a0f] [cat isMemberOfClass:[Cat class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:51:35.156 EmptyFoundation[83741:a0f] [dog isMemberOfClass:[Dog class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:51:35.157 EmptyFoundation[83741:a0f] ![ant isMemberOfClass:[Cat class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:51:35.157 EmptyFoundation[83741:a0f] [cat isKindOfClass:[Animal class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:51:35.157 EmptyFoundation[83741:a0f] [dog isKindOfClass:[Animal class]] PASSED
2010-01-11 19:51:35.158 EmptyFoundation[83741:a0f] [ant isKindOfClass:[Animal class]] PASSED
```

EDIT #2:

Based on your observation that an if...else if statement works but the switch statement does not, I modified the code I posted above to use a switch statement.... and it worked just fine.  So my comment/question stands:  In your if/switch statements, you're using these constants `DOG` and `CAT`.  Where are those defined?

Comment: Well, I tried to create instances using [Cat new] directly and everything works....so the problem is inside farm

Comment: @Vitek - how are you defining `CAT` and `DOG`?

Answer (score -10):

You are missing breaks, that's why your switch isn't working. It should look like this.

```
switch (type) {

 case CAT:
   return [Cat new];
 break;
 case DOG:
   return [Dog new];
 break;
 default:
   return [Animal new];
 break;
}
```