# What is the difference between these inheritance checks?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen examples of Objective-C code apparently doing the same/similar checks using different methods. I want to learn what's the difference in these:

```
isKindOfClass

isMemberOfClass

isSubclassOfClass
```

Please also mention if there is a check that I have not mentioned here, because I am learning and have a very poor command at things at the moment.

Comment: This question will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045561/objective-c-iskindofclass-missunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many link on google and specially it has been asked on stackoverflow many times, check my added link in comment and,

[iPhone SDK difference between isKindOfClass and isMemberOfClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/iphone-sdk-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass)

Try reading their documentation as well, that will help you a lot.

**Edited**

Lets say you have a class name `External` and inside `External` class you have a subclass named `Internal`. I hope you have idea about class can have a subclass which can access properties of a main class. so by this method you can ask an `Internal` class that , **Are you a subclass of External class?**

```
[Internal isSubclassOfClass:External]
```

And return value will be `BOOL`

- YES if the receiving class is a subclass of—or identical to—aClass,
  otherwise NO.

More reading is available on documentation website of Apple

[http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html](http://Developer%20website%20reference%20to%20isSubClassOfClass%20method.)

Comment: agree but what about isSubclassOfClass

Answer (score 6):

These are both instance methods:

`isKindOfClass:` Is the object an instance of a class, or an instance of a subclass of that class?
`isMemberOfClass:` Is the object is an instance of a class? (Does not include subclasses).

Whereas the last one is a class method, (e.g. `[NSString isSubclassOfClass:[NSObject class]]`).

`isSubclassOfClass:` Is a *class* equal to another class, or a subclass of that class?