# Test type of NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotification

I need to check whether an object is an NSNotification. It is not enough to know if it is a subclass, as I want to differentiate between whether it is an NSNotification or a subclass of NSNotification.

So to elaborate I need to differentiate between the following:

1. An NSConcreteNotification
2. A Subclass of NSNotification (But not NSConcreteNotification)

The problem is that NSNotifications are actually NSConcreteNotifications and NSConcreteNotification is a private class so I can't use it to test against.

```
[object isMemberOfClass: [NSNotification class]] // returns NO in both cases
[object isKindOfClass: [NSNotification class]] // returns YES in both cases
```

Comment: The object you test against is a subclass of NSNotification no?

Comment: You can use isMemberOfClass method of objective-C. Please refer [isMemberOfClass][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045561/objective-c-iskindofclass-missunderstanding

Comment: The object could be 1. An NSConcreteNotification or 2. A subclass of NSNotification. I need to tell the difference.

Comment: i've updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to subclass `NSNotification` the way you're describing. First, `NSNotification` already carries a userInfo dictionary. You can put any data you want in there. You can use category methods to read and write into that dictionary if you like (I do this all the time). For example, a very common thing I want to do is pass along some object, say the `RNMessage`. So I create a category that looks like this:

```
@interface NSNotificationCenter (RNMessage)
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject message:(RNMessage *)message;
@end

@interface NSNotification (RNMessage)
- (RNMessage *)message;
@end
```

---

```
static NSString * const RNMessageKey = @"message";

@implementation NSNotificationCenter (RNMessage)
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject message:(RNMessage *)message {
  [self postNotificationName:aName object:anObject userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:RNMessageKey];
}
@end

@implementation NSNotification (RNMessage)
- (RNMessage *)message {
  return [[self userInfo] objectForKey:RNMessageKey];
}
```

As @hypercrypt notes, you can also use associated references to attach data to any arbitrary object without creating an ivar, but with `NSNotification` it's much simpler to use the userInfo dictionary. It's much easier to print notification using `NSLog`. Easier to serialize them. Easier to copy them. Etc. Associated references are great, but they do add lots of little corner cases that you should avoid if you can get away with it.

Comment: Very nice. This is really helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To test id object is an `NSNotification` use:

```
[object isMemberOfClass:[NSNotification class]];`
```

To test if it is a `NSConcreteNotifications` use

```
[object isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSConcreteNotifications")];
```

Change the string to the name of a different class as needed...

You can then combine the two check for 'A Subclass of NSNotification (But not NSConcreteNotification'.

Either:

```
if ([object isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSConcreteNotifications")])
{
    // It's a NSConcreteNotifications...
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNotification class]])
{
    // It's an NSNotification (or subclass) but not an NSConcreteNotifications
}
```

Or

```
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNotification class]] && ![object isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSConcreteNotifications")])
{ /* ... */ }
```

If you want to add properties to `NSNotification`s  you should look into [Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html).

The basic idea is:

```
static const char objectKey;
- (id)object
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &objectKey);
}

- (void)setObject:(id)object
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &objectKey, object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But using a string seems like a really unsafe way of doing it. It seems bizarre that we would have to resort to hard coding a string for such a simple task.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between the two?

Comment: I'm mapping Notifications to Commands and I want the option for this to be Strongly typed. Relying on a string (the notification's name) is a bad way to go in my opinion.

Comment: But so is interrogating implementation detail... An `NS*Notification` should be just like a `NSNotification` to us...

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a really bad idea. When you first receive the notification, you already know what type it is, because it's passed as an explicit argument to a notification callback method. Consider storing the notification as a strongly typed property of another object, or inserting in a dictionary under an appropriate key if you're adding it to a collection, or passing it to other methods that don't preserve the type information to make it easier to identify later.

Creating dependencies on private API (including the names of private classes) will make your code more fragile, and much more likely to break in a future release. Obviously, one of the reasons these classes are private is to make it easier for Apple's engineers to change them as they see fit. For example, the concrete subclasses used by NSArray and NSMutableArray just changed in a recent release of the SDK.

Comment: I fully understand that it is a bad idea, which is why I'm trying to find an alternative. I want to use notifications with custom properties which means I have no choice but to subclass NSNotification which Apple says is fine in its documentation. Part of my requirement is that when I receive a notification I can check whether or not it is an NSNotification or a subclass of NSNotification so I can act appropriately.

Comment: You can add properties without subclassing using categories using associated objects...

Comment: I was under the impression it was impossible to sythesize properties in a category?

Comment: It is, but you can use associated object instead. Have a look at this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html Have a look at my updated answer...

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Rather than checking the class, perhaps you could use `respondsToSelector:` to check for the existence of the property accessors before attempting to reference them. Better yet, you could create a custom protocol, and have your subclasses adopt it, and then check for the protocol dynamically as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it is a bad idea to rely on the name of a private class. If you are looking for one specific subclass, you could just explicitly check for that class.

```
[notification isMemberOfClass:[MyNotificationSubclass class]];
```

You could use multiple statements to check for multiple subclasses, but that would be a little cluttered. This method also requires changes every time you add a new class to look for. It may be better to define a readonly property which indicates whether a notification supports the feature you are looking for, so you aren't relying on the class so much as the ability of the class. You could use a category on NSNotification which simply returns `NO` for this property, and any subclasses which have the feature would override the method to return `YES`.

```
@interface NSNotification (MyFeature)
@property (readonly) BOOL hasMyFeature;
@end

@implementation NSNotification (MyFeature)
- (BOOL)hasMyFeature {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

In the subclasses which support it:

```
- (BOOL)hasMyFeature {
    return YES;
}
- (void)performMyFeature {
    ...
}
```

This would also allow you to change whether or not a notification has the feature enabled by changing a flag which is returned for `hasMyFeature`, and your checking code would simply be:

```
if(notification.hasMyFeature) [notification performMyFeature];
```

Comment: More idiomatic (shorter to implement, longer to use) would probably be `if ([notification respondsToSelector:@selector(performMyFeature)]) [notification performMyFeature];` and then you don't need the `hasMyFeature` property anymore.

Comment: @Quuxplusone True. Thinking about it now, you could also have the category add an empty `performMyFeature` method too, then you wouldn't need to check at all. But I'm going to leave it as it is, because I prefer that style in many cases.