# Why isn't my NSMutableArray of type NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, introspection

I got an NSMutableArray, created like this:

```
NSMutableArray *expr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    [expr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.0]];
    [expr addObject:@"+"];
    [expr addObject:@"%x"];
    [expr addObject:@"*"];
    [expr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.0]];
```

Later on, I pass it to  method where it is known as `(id) anExpression`, and I try to determine what kind of object this is with introspection:

```
if ([[anExpression class] isEqual:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    // Some code I only want to do if it IS a Mutable array
}
```

But, that returns false, and my code isn't executed. I tried `NSLog`'ing `[NSMutableArray class]` and that gives me `NSMutableArray`. Not quite a surprise.
But when I try `NSLog`'ing `expr`'s class, I get `__NSArrayM`.

Why is this? How should I get around this?

I am not that familiar with Objective-C, so please explain things. I don't like doing things I don't understand.

Comment: I believe your array is going through a change somewhere down the line. Can you show us more code where  you do work with that NSMutableArray?

Comment: There is nothing else. That's the first thing I do with this array except for passing it into a method. @RyanPoolos

Comment: Then can we see the method? My guess is your method is the problem then. can we see is interface and implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check is incorrect. It should be either

```
if ([[expr class] isEqual:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
```

or

```
if ([expr isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
```

Comment: I'll accept in 8 minutes. But another question: As you see I put NSStrings and NSNumbers in there, but I get them back as NS**CF**Strings and NS**CF**Numbers. Why?

Comment: That's the core foundation format. There's a toll free bridging between Cocoa formats and Core foundation formats (i.e. they are functionally equal). You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677-SW1)

Comment: So you say I can do everything that I can do with a string with an NSCFString?

Comment: Yes, check out the link at the end of my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in  isKindOfClass - clearly you would want to execute the code reserved for mutable arrays if you created a subclass of an NSMutableArray.

In the same way, there must be some internal Cocoa implementation detail where the class of the the mutable array that you made is different from [NSMutableArray class]. I don't know the reason, but you should not care either, you almost always want to use isKindOfClass - which works for subclasses too.

### If you do care to find out...

Its all about class clusters - see [Objective c isKindOfClass missunderstanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045561/objective-c-iskindofclass-missunderstanding)